# Embed PDF on shared drive into an HTML email

Tags: python, html, pdf, embed

My python script is creating a PDF that is stored on a shared T: drive. I want to take this PDF and embed it into the body of an HTML email script using the file path. I have sent HTML emails before with images embedded but they have always come from an online source.

Like "src = https:// www . somewebsite.com/image.jpg"

Is there a way to embed this PDF using just the file path?

Thank you

Comment: you can't use `path` to your drive `T:` because it is not avaliable for other users. You have to learn how to create `multipart` email and send full PDF directly in email. And it this file will have uniq `content ID` and HTML will use link with this `content ID`

Comment: if you send to users which have the same drive also as `T:` then you could try to use url with `file://T:/full/path/to/file.pdf` - but if they have it with different letter then you can't send it as path.

Comment: Thank you, @furas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a workaround. Made my PDFs into jpegs and then did this:

```
data = open(rf'path.jpg', 'rb').read()  # read bytes from file
data_base64 = base64.b64encode(data)  # encode to base64 (bytes)
data_base64 = data_base64.decode()  # convert bytes to string
code = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data_base64 + '">'  # embed in html
open('output.html', 'w').write(code) #add html to a text file to be read by email
```